# Operation on implicit column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `merge` dataframe and code. I do not receive an error but the code run without ending. I want to divide each column with a date by `circualtion supply`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
          currency  2019-06-28 00:00:00  2019-06-29 00:00:00  2019-06-30 00:00:00  2019-07-01 00:00:00  circulating_supply  total_supply
    0        1WO         1.328080e+06         1.438580e+06         1.381592e+06         1.235750e+06            20981450      37219452
    2        ADH         1.315157e+05         1.485305e+05         1.304471e+05         1.208300e+05           131376614     392000000
    3        ALX         9.692500e+03         1.141000e+04         1.187750e+04         9.432500e+03           502909380    1000000000
```

My code:

```
    created_at = pd.date_range(start= datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=3), datetime.min.time()),   end= datetime.combine(datetime.today() , datetime.min.time()) )
    concentration = merge.iloc[:,:len('created_at')-1] / merge['circulating_supply']
```